# Generate headers in Twisted client

Tags: python, http, client, twisted

i'm using the Twisted web "HTTPClient" protocol to dialogue with a http server (using twisted app as a client), the problem is that most of my request do not accept my header. Is there some sort of way (maybe using certain libraries) to generate header??
I'll post some code so you can have a look

```
class Local(HTTPClient):
def generateHeaders(self, type=None):
    self.sendHeader('User-Agent', 'Twisted Web Client')
    if type:
        self.sendHeader('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded')
    self.sendHeader('Accept', '*/*')
    self.sendHeader('Host', 'localhost')
    self.endHeaders()

def connectionMade(self):
    ## GENERATE ID
    self.userid= self.generateID()
    self.sendCommand('POST', '/chat/action=join&user=pirosb3')
    self.generateHeaders(type=True)

def dataReceived(self, data):
    print data
```

As you can see, i created a method that generates header for me, but not very efficient i must say, i always get error responses.

Anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't describe the problem in enough detail for anyone to help, I think.  What does "not very efficient" mean?  What about "my request do not accept my header"?  Why doesn't `sendHeader` "generate [a] header" suitable for you?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend you to use Twisted's `Agent` class along with the `Header` class in the `twisted.web.http_headers` module.

There is a nice guide available [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/web/howto/client.html).

If you need a real life example of a Twisted HTTP client which adds some headers to the request and can read the ones of the answer, here it is:

```
from pprint import pformat

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.remaining = 1024 * 10

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self.remaining:
            display = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print 'Some data received:'
            print display
            self.remaining -= len(display)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        self.finished.callback(None)

agent = Agent(reactor)
d = agent.request(
    'GET',
    'http://example.com/',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
    None)

def cbRequest(response):
    print 'Response version:', response.version
    print 'Response code:', response.code
    print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
    print 'Response headers:'
    print pformat(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(BeginningPrinter(finished))
    return finished
d.addCallback(cbRequest)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```